# Is there an authoritative list of chemical reactions/transformations?

Tags: reference-request, books

Is there somewhere where I can find an authoritative list of chemical reactions, energy requirements, known catalysts, etc.? If not, how do you know if and how to transform substance A to substance B? What references do you use?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.se! Find out more about this site and take the [tour] and further information can be obtained in the [help]. I retagged your question to fit it into a wider range - the books tag is for literature in general, so please don't be confused.

Comment: Well, you are asking about whole several branches of chermistry - organic/inorganic synthesis/technology - more like a liberary than list, but what's google for :) - you can always try searching on internet